# How can I pass a dictionary from HTML to a Flask Python method?

Tags: python, html, flask

I have a dictionary in a HTML file. I want to be able to download this data in the 'xlsx' (Excel) format. I have the code to convert any Python dictionary into a newly converted Excel file but I don't know how to pass the dictionary from the HTML to the Python/Flask route method.

Comment: you really can't ... you should use js to generate a json from what data you have set in html ... call a url (which is you python / flask server)

Answer (score 1):

Flask Route to get data.

```py
@app.route('/postmethod', methods = ['POST'])
def get_post_javascript_data():
    jsdata = request.get_json() # parse as json
```

AJAX to send JSON data

```js
var person = {"name":"Andrew", "loves":"Open Source"};
var asJSON = JSON.stringify(person);
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", "/postmethod", true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json; charset=utf-8");
xhttp.send(asJSON);
```

Comment: something like that ...